# Oracle pl sql exception block will be executed when

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, oracle11g

If i have an oracle pl/sql procedure, I define an exception block like this:

```
exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN
errMsg := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 100);
  dbms_output.put_line ('--> Error ALIAS1: ' || errMsg);
end;
```

Will this be executed no matter what kind of exception is raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHEN OTHERS` is a catch-all for any PL/SQL exception that isn't handled explicitly by its own `WHEN` clause.

It isn't normally a good idea to use it, for that reason; it's easy to accidentally trap and lose an important message about something bad happening. You should catch and handle the specific exceptions you expect to encounter. If you do want to record or log any other exceptions you should include a `RAISE` in the exception handler so everything else gets propagated normally.

```
...
exception
    when others then
        errMsg := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 100);
        dbms_output.put_line ('--> Error ALIAS1: ' || errMsg);
        raise;
end;
```

Read more about exceptions generally [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_subprograms.htm#BABFIBHE), and about `OTHERS` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exception_handler.htm#LNPLS1066).